# A spectrum $X$ whose cohomology is $H^*(X; \mathbb{F}_2) = A//A(n)$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, spectral-sequences

Computing the Adams spectral sequence is hard. Even determining the $E_2$-page can be difficult, but it can be simplified in some cases. In particular, when $H^*(X; \mathbb{F}_2) = A//A(n)$, for $A$ the mod 2 Steenrod algebra, we can use the change of rings isomorphism:
$$\text{Ext}_A(A//A(n), \mathbb{F}_2) = \text{Ext}_{A(n)}(\mathbb{F}_2, \mathbb{F}_2)$$
I know that $H^*(H\mathbb{Z};\mathbb{F}_2) = A//A(0)$, $H^*(ko; \mathbb{F}_2) = A//A(1)$, and $H^*(tmf; \mathbb{F}_2) = A//A(2)$. What about the higher quotients $A//A(n)$ for $n \geq 2$?

Comment: Wouldn't the presence of a nonzero operation $\textrm{Sq}^{2^n}$ with $n > 3$ on the bottom class violate Hopf invariant one?

Comment: See this [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/393249/spectrum-e-with-h-bullete-mathbbz-2-mathcala-mathcalan) on Math Overflow, for slightly more fleshed out version of John Palmieri's comment.

Comment: @JHF this gave a good answer and made clear Palmieri’s response. Thanks!